# How to improve the Replace function in CLR function?

Tags: c#, regex, sql-server-2008, replace, sqlclr

I have a CLR function to replace string values.
but it runs a long time. How can I improve this function and make it runs faster?

```
    public static SqlString ReplaceValues(String Value)
    {
    // Put your code here
    char[] c = new char[] { '.' };
    Value= Value.Trim();
    Value = Value.Trim(c);
    Value = Value.Replace("'", "").Replace(")", " ").Replace("(", " ").Replace("-", " ").Replace("_", " ");

    Value = Regex.Replace(Value, @"[י", "+[י");
    Value = Regex.Replace(Value, @"\s+", " ");

    return new SqlString(Value.Trim());

   }
```

EDIT:
I changed my function to use value.Replace, it's better, but still it runs more time than expected:

```
     public static SqlString ReplaceStreetValues(String Value)
    {
    // Put your code here
    Value = Value.Trim();
    char[] c = new char[]{'.'}; 
    Value = Value.Trim(c);

    Value= Value.Replace("'", "").Replace(")", " ").Replace("(", " ").Replace("-", " ").Replace("_", " ").Replace("רח", "");
   while (Value.IndexOf("  ")!=-1)
        Value = Value.Replace("  ", " ");
   while (Value.IndexOf("hh") !=-1)        
        Value = Value.Replace("hh", "h");

    return new SqlString(Value.Trim());

    }
```

thanks!!!

Comment: What is the execution time of that method, and what input do you supply? Have you timed this in release mode outside of Visual Studio (no debugger attached)?

Comment: I call this method from sqlServer in a select query for about 400 records, and for each record I send a word or two to the function, not something long... and it runs for about 40 sec.

Comment: What is the performance of that query without calling this function?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [StringBuilder.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h5afh4w.aspx) instead.

*Should* notably improve performance.

This is valid like a `string.Replace(..)` substitude and not for `regex` calls.
But apparently the bottleneck is in `string` calls.

**EDIT**:

Example (*pesudocode*):

```
char[] c = new char[]{'.', ' '}; 
Value = Value.Trim(c);
var sb = new StringBuilder(Value);   

sb.Replace("'", "");
sb.Replace(")", " ");
sb.Replace("(", " ");
sb.Replace("-", " ");
sb.Replace("_", " ");
sb.Replace("רח", "");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my question, see the changes.

Comment: @mnmn: why don't you use `StringBuilder` ?

Comment: Can you provide me code example how to use it in my case? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it'll take less time. I changed something else so I don't need to use the CLR function. Thanks again!