# SQL Nested Replace

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a complex nested replace which I am using to join two tables in MSSQL.

```
select * from A
  left outer join 
select * from B
on
  replace(
     replace(
        replace(
           replace(
              replace(A.Column1, '1114', ''),
             '1160', ''), 
          '1162', ''),
        '1167', ''),
      '1176', ''),
    '1177', '')  = B.Column1
```

The whole reason I am doing this is because data in Table1 contains of some *noise* - numbers like *1160*, *1162* etc wheres Table2 is clean characters.

```
Eg. - Table 1 - 'HELLO1160WORLD'
      Table 2 - 'HELLOWORLD'
```

Now in my situation I should be able to **match** them as one entry.

My current approach of nested replace does work but I am not convinced that this is an elegant way to do this. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I hope that you are using `SELECT *` for illustrative purposes and not as practice.

Comment: can you post some sample data and then show what you want the final result to be?

Comment: Sure.  What do you need help with?

Comment: Yes I am not actually using * - just for making things simpler.

Ill edit the original question to make it clearer

Comment: It may not be pretty, but if you're only dealing with a small subset of numbers, the above method is fine.  Not pretty, but fine.

Comment: is `'HELLO1160WORLD'` a valid piece of data? if yes, bummer. if no, why not sanitize on the front end?

Comment: I believe CLR procedure would do the trick. Something like that is already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069373/how-to-improve-the-replace-function-in-clr-function). If that is what you consider elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that T-SQL does not easily allow to mark expressions with a name so you can refer to them from a different place. There is a way to do this though:

```
select replaceN
from T
cross apply (select replace1 = replace(T.col, 'x', 'y')) r1
cross apply (select replace2 = replace(replace1, 'x', 'y')) r2
cross apply (select replace3 = replace(replace2, 'x', 'y')) r3
...
```

This at least gets rid of the crazy nesting. It has no negative performance impact.

Comment: This is a good solution... once I understood it.  "replaceN" being the highest numbered replace in the sequence, in this example it is replace3

Answer (score 4):

Maybe use a function to strip the [non-numeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server/1008566#1008566):

```
Create Function [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

    While PatIndex('%[^a-z]%', @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex('%[^a-z]%', @Temp), 1, '')

    Return @Temp
End
```

Then you will reference this function in your join:

```
select a.col1 a, b.col1 b
from tablea a
left join tableb b
  on dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharacters(a.col1) = b.col1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85a85/1)

Comment: Thanks, that would be an elegant solution. The only problem is that I don't want to remove all non-apha numerics. Sorry for not being clear.

There could be cases such as 

`HELLO1114WORLD1` and `HELLOWORLD1`

I have a very specific set of values (transaction codes to be specific) which I would like to remove

Comment: @dopplesoldner so those two values would not be a match then?  Can you post a larger data sample and then the expected result?

Comment: Hi @bluefeet

I would like the following values to be treated as **matching**

`HELLO1114WORLD1 HELLOWORLD1`
`M125ICKY1114MOUSE M125ICKYMOUSE`
`RONA1160DINHO10 RONALDINHO10`

Currently by using my nested replace, I am replacing certain known identifiers - eg `1114`, `1160` to give me exact matches. Hope it helps and thanks again!

Comment: @dopplesoldner can you apply the function to both columns?  similar to this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11e59/1

Comment: But that would match `M125ICKY1114MOUSE` to `M999ICKYMOUSE` ?

Comment: Btw thanks for showing me SQL FIddle, I had never heard of it!

Answer (score 0):

Bluefeet's suggestion would do definitely do a good job of making your query much simpler.  However, if you don't want to bother with a function and keep all your code one place, try this.  Before you do the join, you could dump table A into a staging table:

```
DECLARE @TmpA TABLE(
     Column1 [nvarchar] (50)),
     ...
     )

Insert into @tmpA select * from A

Update @TmpA set Column1=Replace(Replace(Replace(Column1,...)))

Select * from tmpA
  left outer join 
Select * from B
  on tmpA.Column1=B.Column1
```

Comment: But this way, I am still left with the nasy nested loop. (which I am trying to avoid in the first place)

Comment: Correct, but it would at least move the nested loop out of the Join and into it's own section.